# How to spell check/ auto correct in aws lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex, autocorrect

I am building a chatbot using AWS lex and lambda. It is working fine for the correct spelling of words in sentences but fails when some words are miss-spelt. How can I make it work for miss-spelt words? I am using javascript in lambda.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate user input using the initialization and validation codeHook. This code gets executed at every turn of the conversation.

The codehook can be used to validate user input.
You can use a lambda to do a spelling validation. There should be some libraries available that provide this in javascript.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/spellchecker

https://github.com/vesln/teacher

Amazon lex does not provide Spell check out of the box. Microsoft has a better solution in my opinion.